# Make jQuery/AJAX perform instantly on page load

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Is it possible to make content load instantly from AJAX?

For example, on load I use `$.getJSON`:

```
$(function(){
  $.getJSON('posts.php',function(data){
    data.posts.forEach(function(post){
       // load info, append divs
    })
  })
 })
```

There is however a slight delay (maybe 1 second) where the `divs` aren't appended on page load. Is this only possible if you use PHP `on-load`?

Comment: It takes the time it takes, there's no way to do ajax "instantly"

Comment: The slight delay is due to the asynchronous request being made. This is how AJAX works and there is nothing you can do except either decrease the size of the data returned so that it loads quicker, or speed up the time the request takes to be processed on the server.

Comment: Like the others have mentioned, this is the way it works when using AJAX.  But I gotta ask, if you want it to be instant, how come you don't just simply load the initial data on the server side, instead of rendering a "blank" page and using a second request to fetch the data?

Comment: @ HaukurHaf - I haven't learned how to do this server-side using PHP code yet, so I'm not sure how to go about it. Also I couldn't really be bothered to re-do it all.

Comment: Depending on what the content and context are, there are some possibilities. If it is a slideshow, you could preload the prev and next images, and just show/hide with CSS. Same could potentially be done with pagination of posts etc. Preload content in a hidden div, then show it later. If there is variables you need from php to use in scripts, you could set and get them with html5 datasets. Other than that, all I can think of is the already mentioned loading icon/indication to alert the user of impending content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The speed of an Ajax call is the speed of an Ajax call.  It's a roundtrip to the server so once you've made that roundtrip as fast as it can be on your server, there's nothing else you can do as the rest is just the speed of the transport between your server and the client browser.  So, there will always be some sort of delay.

There are some things you can do as a work-around:

1. You can send the ajax call immediately in the `<head>` tag rather than waiting for the page to load.  When the result comes back, you just store the result.  Then, when the page is done loading, you instantly insert the result.
2. You can hide your main content, run the ajax call, insert the ajax result, then show your content.  This will make it all "appear" on screen at once.

The first option would look like this:

```
<head>
  <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  $.when($.getJSON('posts.php'), jQuery.ready).then(function(result) {
      // result[0] is the result from the getJSON call
      // and the DOM is ready so you can insert the content here
  });
  </script>
</head>
```

This starts the ajax call immediately as the page starts to load to get it started as soon as possible.  Then, when both the ajax call is done and the DOM is ready, you can insert the content.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a UX issue. What you can do is make it "perceived" as instant. For example, does it have an Ajax loader? Can you fade in the content when ready? There are lots of tricks you can do to make it "instant". I do agree, you can't just randomly pop stuff into the page. That can frighten people.

Comment: At the moment I have a "dummy" div with a loading gif icon. It's not ideal (instant) but I suppose it's good enough.

Comment: I agree, it communicates something is loading on the page